# HDMI cable stopped working in 16.04

Tags: hdmi

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in a laptop. I was using a shared screen with another monitor for work. Suddenly, when I turned on the system, HDMI is not working. If I connect the cable with monitor, the monitor turns from hibernate to on but didn't display anything. It does not work with the one more monitor as well.

Comment: Did you update your system or make any changes to it between when it last worked?  Something else you might want to rule out is whether or not the cable is broken...sometimes bending it over time will shorten its life...

Comment: The cable and monitor are new. The laptop 3 years old. I have updated or changed any system.

Comment: You have or you have not?  You really need to provide more information if you would like someone to help you...

Comment: Sorry for the vague reply. I have two HDMI cables; separate for each of the monitor. I have checked with both the monitor using different cables. It is less likely that there would be problem in cable or monitor.

Comment: Perhaps you should revise your question a bit with all of the information you can provide, including what you've done to the system just before the problem occurred.  The more information you provide, the more likely someone (not necessarily me) can help you.  Also, as you provide more information, the more likely you might find a way to help yourself.  You originally said "Suddenly" and few things with computers happen "Suddenly"...something has changed...

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is my first time posting a question. I will be specific next time. I got the solution. Sorry for being vague again. But I opened the Ubuntu in recovery mode & it got fixed.